# How to connect a 3 PIN photo-diode ? Specifically Hamamatsu S5973-03

Tags: led, photodiode

I am trying to receive a 1MHz square pulse generated using a LED. But the square pulse I get from the photo diode is extremely distorted. I am unsure about the way I am connecting the photo diode. Please let me know if you guys need any extra information.

Comment: Can you provide a link to the photodiode datasheet (searching hamamatsu's website for that pn gives nothing)? Also, have you checked your LED output with a different receiver so you know that is not the issue?

Comment: And what circuit are you connecting to the photodiode?

Comment: https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=S5973-03&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gws_rd=cr&ei=0n24VeTVC--M7Aa-6YCQCQ

Comment: http://www.farnell.com/datasheets/8750.pdf

Comment: Yes, I have tried with another already built receiver, I do get a square pulse. No other circuits are connected to it as of now. But I was told that a faint square signal should at-least be received from the photo-diode.

Comment: What load resistor and bias voltage are you using?

Comment: -1 for no schematic.

Comment: And there's no S5973-03 part mentioned in the datasheet you linked. You need to give us the datasheet of your actual part, and the schematic of the circuit you're using, or there's no possible way we can explain what you might be doing wrong.

Comment: The bias voltage I used was 3.3V as mentioned in the datasheet.

Comment: There is no schematic as such , just the photo-diode connected in series with a resistor and the oscilloscope output taken from the resistor. Or like shown below output is taken right after the TIA

Comment: You really need to draw a schematic. What you describe sounds completely wrong (a photodiode produces current, and an oscilloscope measures voltage, so why do you put the resistor in series?), but it is not possible to correct anything without some sort of reference point. Also, as it has been repeatedly stated and as you can plainly see by reading it, the datasheet you link does **not** include anything for the S5973-03. Either you are mistaken about which diode you use, or you have twice specified an incorrect datasheet. I'm sorry to say it, but for all this, you earned my downvote.

Answer (score 1):

[S5973-03](http://www.farnell.com/datasheets/8750.pdf) is here and you should really use a TIA (transimpedance amplifier) for this device: -

[image]

See also [this](https://www.hamamatsu.com/resources/pdf/ssd/si_pd_kspd0001e.pdf) document from Hamamatsu (page 44 and 45)

Comment: Any specific Op-Amps I need to use for the TIA, cause I don't get any square wave. And where does the 3rd pin go to , in data sheet it says "CASE" does that mean ground.

Comment: Case goes to 0V on your circuit usually. Recommending specific op-amps is frowned upon. If you can find one that you think is OK, post a link in a comment.

Comment: @BoominPerera which op-amp you use is dependent on your requirements for bandwidth, noise, sensitivity, and probably some other factors as well, so it is not possible to make a specific recommendation. So far as I know, S5973-03 is not a standard part (I did not contact Hamamatsu to ask about it, but I did contact them about custom S5973 models in the past, and they did not mention it then). Please post the datasheet for this specific model, if you are allowed to. If its electrical characteristics are the same as for the other S5973 diodes, then please specify that.

Comment: OK broken link working @OleksandrR.

Comment: http://www.hamamatsu.com/resources/pdf/ssd/s5971_etc_kpin1025e.pdf Thats the data sheet for the photo-diode , i have used AD8010A for the TIA Op-Amp http://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/AD8010.pdf